# Automatically cancel binary execution when certain output is detected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, executable, binaryfiles

Is it possible to somehow run an executable through the shell and automatically make it stop executing the moment a specific string is matched/detected in the output? Just as if i would hit CTRL+C, manually?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
program | awk '/pattern/{exit}1'
```

If you also want to print the line containing the *pattern*, say:

```
program | awk '/pattern/{print;exit}1'
```

For example:

```
$ seq 200 | awk '/9/{print;exit}1'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

---

EDIT: (With reference to your comment, whether the program would stop or not.)  Following is a script that would execute in an infinite loop:

```
n=1
while : ; do
  echo $n
  n=$((n+1))
  sleep 1
done
```

This script `foo.sh` was executed by saying:

```
$ time bash foo.sh | awk '/9/{print;exit}1'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

real    0m9.097s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.011s
```

As you can see, the script terminated when the pattern was detected in the output.

---

EDIT: It seems that your program buffers the output.  You could use `stdbuf`:

```
stdbuf -o0 yourprogram | awk '/pattern/{print;exit}1'
```

If you're using `mawk`, then say:

```
stdbuf -o0 yourprogram | mawk -W interactive '/pattern/{print;exit}1'
```

Comment: It seems that using this, the program is still having to finish. It takes as long as if i call it without awk. Is this possible?

Comment: @SquareCat No, the program should finish.  `awk` would send a `SIGPIPE` to the program which should terminate it.  See the edit above for a demo.

Comment: If the program produces output slowly, it could run for a while before the `SIGPIPE` is generated, though.

Comment: @tripleee Good thought, I'll suggest using `stdbuf`.

Comment: @SquareCat It seems that the output is buffered; the edit above might work for you.

Comment: If I want to use this in a loop within a script: Can I replace the `exit` with a `continue`? And what does the `1` stand for?i

Comment: Ah I got it. Exit is only exiting the program, not the script. Sure. My workaround to continue in a loop is to give an exit code unequal to zero and ask for that 
`program | awk '/pattern/{exit 2}1'`
`if [[ $? -eq 2 ]];then
     continue;
fi`

Answer (score 4):

use a coprocess:

```
coproc CO { yourcommand; }
while read -ru ${CO[0]} line
do
    case "$line" in
        *somestring*) kill $CO_PID; break ;;
    esac
done
```

Note that if the command buffers its output, as many commands do when writing to a pipe, there will be some delay before the string is detected.

Comment: I don't find any `coproc` binary on my system. I'm on Mac OSX, should have included that in my question though.

Comment: It's not a binary, it's built into bash 4.x. Unfortunately, OS X has bash 3.x. If you google bash coprocesses, you can find out how to do the same thing using named pipes.